# java:After entering id whole information should display

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I have created one form, which contain information of user like name, contact no, photo id number, job profile etc. Once he enter all the information, it will store in database. When he login for second time, after entering photo id number whole information should display on the form, without he enters. I am using key typed event for this. I have tried this code, but it is throwing exception as

> java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

```
public void show()
{
   try
   {
        String id=photo_id_num.getText();
        System.out.println(""+id);          
        Connect c=new Connect();
        con=c.getConnection();
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String queryPhotoid = "select *  from tbl_visitor ";
        ResultSet rs1= stmt.executeQuery(queryPhotoid);    
              while (rs1.next()) 
              {
              if(id.equals(rs1.getString(6)))
              {
        // Read values using column name
            String name = rs1.getString(2);
            int contno = rs1.getInt(3);
                String orgname = rs1.getString(4);
                String jobpro = rs1.getString(5);
                String category = rs1.getString(7);
                String date = rs1.getString(8);
                int noofpeople = rs1.getInt(9);
                Blob image = rs1.getBlob(10);
                int extrapeople = rs1.getInt(11);

             System.out.println("Name:"+name+" Contact_no:"+contno+"Org_Name:"+orgname+" Job_profile:"+jobpro+"Category:"+category+"Date:"+date+"No_Of_People:"+noofpeople+"image:"+image+"Having extra people:"+extrapeople);
          }
              }
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlEx)
    {
         sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `catch (SQLException sqlEx) { ..` should be `catch (SQLException sqlEx)
 { sqlEx.printStackTrace(); ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fetch result set the cursor is prior to the first record so you need to take cursor to the first record by executing `resultSet.next()`, Here in your case you are reading before positioning the cursor

```
System.out.println("ranu"+rs1.getString(6));  
while (rs1.next());
```

So you first need to do `rs.next()` then only you can read the records

So make it as follows

```
ResultSet rs1= stmt.executeQuery(queryPhotoid);    

while (rs1.next())  {

  System.out.println("ranu"+rs1.getString(6));  
  if(id.equals(rs1.getString(6)))
  {
  // blah blah..
  }
//blah
}
```

Comment: I have tried as per your suggestion, bur still it is throwing same excetion.

Comment: update the updated code and exception stacktrace in the question please

Comment: You also have to put the code `if(id.equals(rs1.getString(6)))` after you have called rs1.next().

Comment: @Anjali please add stacktrace too